# Conditionally copy content from external XML file

Tags: xslt

I have 2 XML files that I need to merge together (XML1 and XML2). I need to conditionally add content from XML2 into XML1 based on whether an attribute is negative or positive.

Ex. XML1

```
<containers>
    <basket1>
    </basket1>
    <basket2>
    </basket2>
</containers>
```

Ex. XML 2

```
<fruit>
    <apple attr="1"/>
    <apple attr="-1"/>
</fruit>
```

Ex. Output

```
<containers>
    <basket1>
       <apple attr="1">
    </basket1>
    <basket2>
       <apple attr="-1"/>
    </basket2>
</containers>
```

As you can see, I don't want to modify XML1's structure accept to add the content based on the value of "attr".

I'm sure there is a good solution to this, but I'm drawing blanks on how to fit the bits and pieces to together. Any help is appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: are you familiar with Xpath? what language are you working with (c/c++/c#/java etc)? edit: just saw the tag, so you want to do it with xslt alone?

Comment: @Ron.B.I I'd like to use XSLT, but this will 1 step in a series of transforms executed within a Java application. If Java can boost the functionality, that is OK. Edited to say that I'm using Saxon 9 as the parser. I'm indifferent between XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Whatever works best.

Comment: if you want to do it in Java I can assist you, I'm unfamiliar with the Saxon 9 parser however, are you familiar with Xpath/Xquery?

Comment: @Ron.B.I Any help is appreciated, but don't be offended if I gravitate toward an XSLT solution in the long run. I'm very familiar with XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear how much generic it should be - so might be it is not exactly what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fruit" select="document('XML2.xml')/fruit" />

    <xsl:template match="/containers">
        <containers>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'positive'" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[2]">
                <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'negative'" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>      </containers>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:param name="type" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$type = 'positive'">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$fruit/*[@attr &gt;= 0]" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$type = 'negative'">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$fruit/*[@attr &lt; 0]" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expects the XML1 is the input file, the XML2 I load into a variable.
There should be some improvement done, like checking if in attribute is really a number etc.

Comment: I've gotten this working for me. Thank you! How can I ensure any attributes on basket1 and basket2 are copied across also? <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> is throwing errors for me.

Comment: Nvm about the attribute bit. I've gotten it working. Answer accepted!